# Codeigniter - Searching for records between two dates 1064 error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I keep getting this error every time I go to the chargeticket_list page.

**Controller**

```
public function chargeticket_list() {
$data['charge_tickets'] = $this->Chargeticket_model->list_charges($this->input->post('date1'), $this->input->post('date2'));
$this->load->view( 'inc/header' );
$this->load->view( 'chargeticket/chargeticket_list', $data );
$this->load->view( 'inc/footer' );
}
```

**Model**

```
public function list_charges($date1, $date2) //This function returns an array
    {   $this->db->join( 'customers', 'charges.idcustomers = customers.idcustomers' );
        $this->db->where('ch_date >=', $date1);
        $this->db->where('ch_date <=', $date2);
        $query = $this->db->get('charges'); //create query
        return $query->result_array(); //creates array from query
    }
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.date1').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.date2').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>

<div class="container">
<?php 
    $attributes = array('id'=>'chargeticket_list', 'class'=> 'form-horizontal');
    echo form_open('chargeticket/chargeticket_list', $attributes);
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php $ldata = array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-4');
    echo form_label('From','date1', $ldata ); 
    $data = array('class' => 'form-control date1','name' => 'date1');?>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo form_input($data);?></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group text-center">
    <?php $ldata = array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-4');
    echo form_label('To','date2', $ldata ); 
    $data = array('class' => 'form-control date2','name' => 'date2');?>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo form_input($data);?></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-center">
    <?php $data = array('class' => 'btn btn-primary','name' => 'submit','value' => 'submit');
    echo form_submit($data); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>  
<br>

<h2 align="center"> Charge Tickets </h2>
<br>


<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])):?>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr class="table-header">
          <td><b>Date Created</b></td>
          <td><b>Posted</b></td>
          <td><b>First Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Charge Ticket #</b></td>
          <td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
          <td><b>View</b></td>
          <td><b>Delete</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($charge_tickets as $object){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $object['ch_date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $object['posted'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['fname']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['lname']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['ch_ticket_id']));?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>      
    <?php } ?>  
  </table>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

The error I continue to get is:
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`NULL` AND `ch_date` < `IS` `NULL`' at line 4

SELECT * FROM `charges` JOIN `customers` ON `charges`.`idcustomers` = `customers`.`idcustomers` WHERE `ch_date` > `IS` `NULL` AND `ch_date` < `IS` `NULL`

Filename: models/Chargeticket_model.php

Line Number: 76

I guess the question I have is why is it trying to access the database before I use the date text fields in the form.

I have another page that I am copying from that **does** work. I can't see how what I am doing is any different from this:

**Controller**

```
public function customer_search() {
    $data[ 'title' ] = 'Customer Search';
    $data[ 'results' ] = $this->Customers_model->search_customers($this->input->post('search')); //excecutes get_customers function
    $this->load->view('inc/header');
    $this->load->view('customers/customer_search', $data);
    $this->load->view('inc/footer');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function search_customers($search) //This function returns an array
{
    $this->db->select('idcustomers, add_name, fname, lname, city, company, marina_reg');
    $this->db->like('fname', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('lname', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('company', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('add_name', $search);
    $query = $this->db->get('customers'); //create query
    return $query->result_array(); //creates array from query
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="container"><h2 class="text-center"><?php echo $title;?></h2>
<br>

<?php 
    $attributes = array('id'=>'search_form', 'class'=> 'form-horizontal');
    echo validation_errors("<p class='bg-danger'>");
    echo form_open('customers/customer_search', $attributes);
?>
<div class="text-center"><p>Search using part of first name, last name or company</p></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $data = array('class' => 'form-control','name' => 'search');?>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo form_input($data);?></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-center">
    <?php $data = array('class' => 'btn btn-primary','name' => 'submit','value' => 'Search Customer');
    echo form_submit($data); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php echo form_close();?>

<?php if ($this->input->post('search')):?>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr class="table-header">
          <td><b>ID</b></td>
          <td><b>Regular</b></td>
          <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
          <td><b>First Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Additional Contact</b></td>
          <td><b>Company</b></td>
          <td><b>City</b></td>
          <td><b>Details</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $object){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $object['idcustomers'];?></td>
      <td>
      <?php 
      if ($object['marina_reg'] == 'Yes'):echo $object['marina_reg'];endif;?>
      </td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['lname']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['fname']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['add_name']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['company']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['city']));?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>customers/customer_edit/<?php echo $object['idcustomers'];?>">Details</a></td>
     </tr>      
    <?php } ?>  
  </table>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In your first controller you should check if form has been posted or not if form has been posted then only try to get data from model. In your second controller it does not through error due to reason that comparison operator are not used

Comment: Could you give me a heads up on how I would do that in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do it like below

```
public function dates_submitted() {
$data['charge_tickets'] = array();
if($this->input->post('date1')!='' && $this->input->post('date2') !=''){
$data['charge_tickets'] = $this->Chargeticket_model->list_charges($this->input->post('date1'), $this->input->post('date2'));
}
$this->load->view( 'inc/header' );
$this->load->view('chargeticket/chargeticket_list', $data);
$this->load->view( 'inc/footer' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SynapseIndia - Thanks for kick starting my thinking. I read this article:

https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-form-input/

and it gave me the code I needed. Here are the changes:

```
    public
    function chargeticket_list() {
        $this->load->view( 'inc/header' );
        $this->load->view( 'chargeticket/chargeticket_list');
        $this->load->view( 'inc/footer' );
    }

    public function dates_submitted() {
        $data['charge_tickets'] = $this->Chargeticket_model->list_charges($this->input->post('date1'), $this->input->post('date2'));
        $this->load->view( 'inc/header' );
        $this->load->view('chargeticket/chargeticket_list', $data);
        $this->load->view( 'inc/footer' );
}
```